# How to change the xslt processor used in a .NET program?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

How to change xslt processor in .net 2.0?

The question can be vague cause I'm totaly noob with that. I used jetbrain to trace my web app
and I saw that xslt transformation take very long time. I folowed [microsoft msdn recommandations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649152.aspx) 
but someone told me to turn (upgrade) my xslt processor to 2.0. to increase performance.

Can you explain me what something about that.

Comment: Which XSLT processor does your current code use, is that System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform or System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform? With .NET 2.0 you should at least use XslCompiledTransform. If you really want to move to XSLT 2.0 then you can move to Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ but I am not sure such a move, without changing stylesheets to exploit XSLT 2.0 features (like for-each-group), will improve performance.

Comment: @Martin Honnen I don't know I've just added System.xml

Comment: How are you currently processing your XSLT? Are you using one of the XslTransform classes or do you just have a xml file linked to a xslt and use the browser to process?

Comment: Christophe, we need to know exactly how you use XSLT in your web app. Do you have C# code running a transformation? Then check whether that code uses XslCompiledTransform or XslTransform. Or are you using one of the ASP.NET server-side controls like the Xml control or like an XmlDataSource where you can provide a stylesheet? I am afraid these controls have never been updated to use XslCompiledTransform.

Comment: @John Saunders: Please, rollback your without reazon edition. Here there is no XSLT question. This is asking for a plataform dependent XSLT processor implementation.

Comment: @Alejandro: that's not how it works.

Comment: @Christophe: BTW, this has nothing to do with ASP.NET or IIS. You cannot "change" the XSLT processor. You simply have to use a different one.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a brief description of the two XSLT processors used in .NET and links to their MSDN documentation. :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev I asked to my workmate he tell me we use XslCompiledTransform

Comment: Christophe, with .NET XslCompiledTransform is the right choice if you want an XSLT 1.0 processor with good performance. You can move to XSLT 2.0 with the .NET version of Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ or with the Beta of XQSharp http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/beta.htm. But you would have to run tests whether those perform better with your existing XSLT 1.0 stylesheets.

Comment: @Christophe-Debove: If you already are running XslCompiledTransform then be assured this is one of the fastest XSLT 1.0 processors (probably the fastest). In case you are having performance problems this most likely means they are algorithmic and would continue to exist regardless the change of processor you make. In this case you must share the code/algorithm and people could help with a better algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to change xslt processor in .net
>   2.0?
>
> someone told me to turn (upgrade) my
>   xslt processor to 2.0. to increase
>   performance.
>
> Can you explain me what something
>   about that.

**There are two XSLT processors shipped with .NET**:

1. [**XslTransform**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx)
2. [**XslCompiledTransform**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)

**As noted in the MSDN documentation**:

> The XslTransform class is obsolete in
>   the Microsoft .NET Framework version
>   2.0. The XslCompiledTransform class is the new XSLT processor.

If you already are running XslCompiledTransform then be assured this is one of the fastest XSLT 1.0 processors (probably the fastest). In case you are having performance problems this most likely means they are algorithmic and would continue to exist regardless the change of processor you make. In this case you must share the code/algorithm and people could help with a better algorithm.